# Google Drive with Google Client Api Android user info

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I am connecting to Drive Api using Google Api Client like this:

```
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

it works great.

Our users now want to see which account (user name) is being used for this, is it possible to do with this api or should I add more, something like G+? The best would be not adding of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the account using the `GoogleApiClient`.

Here is the example from the [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#public-constructor-summary).

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.setAccountName("users.account.name@gmail.com")
.build();
client.connect();
```

About your idea using G+, you can try to check this [page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_add_google_sign-in) about that.

Also try to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960555/how-to-use-googleapiclient-to-provide-credentials-for-cloud-endpoint-client) for more information.

Comment: I want to get the selected account name, which is selected using Google Api Client's dialog.